# Product rule of Conditional probability

Tags: probability

Hello I have the following equality and do not understand how the right site is computed.

$ P(A,B\mid  C) \cdot P(C) = P(A\mid B,C) \cdot P(B\mid C) \cdot P(C) $

I know They used the product rule, but I do not see how and especially I do not understand where the $P(B\mid C)$ comes from, could someone help?

Comment: Could you show us what you have tried so far so that we can provide better help? Especially, it would be interesting how you would define $P(A|B)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have
$$\mathbb P(A,B|C).\mathbb P(C)=\frac{\mathbb P(A\cap B\cap C)}{\mathbb P(C)}.\mathbb P(C)=\mathbb P(A\cap(B\cap C))$$
$$=\frac{\mathbb P(A\cap(B\cap C))}{\mathbb P(B\cap C)}.\mathbb P(B\cap C)=\mathbb P(A|B,C).\mathbb P(B\cap C)$$
Since
$$\mathbb P(B|C)=\frac{\mathbb P(B\cap C)}{\mathbb P (C)}\implies\mathbb P(B\cap C)=\mathbb P(B|C).\mathbb P (C)$$

Hence, replacing $\mathbb P(B\cap C)$ with $\mathbb P(B|C).\mathbb P (C)$ yields
$$\mathbb P(A,B|C).\mathbb P(C)=\mathbb P(A|B,C).\mathbb P(B|C).\mathbb P (C)$$

Comment: I believe that this platform is to provide helps and hints instead of simply giving the answer... @Hamdiken